# What are the black creatures on my pumpkin leaves?

Tags: pests, pumpkins

My Giant Atlantic pumpkins are now 12 weeks old and I've noticed grey/black things on the underside of some of the leaves.
I thought this was a growth of some sort but when touched, they move and seem to be little beetles.

What are they? Do I need to worry about them and if so, what's causing them and how do I get rid of them?

[image: what are these]

Comment: How much more growing is left on your pumpkins?  Neem sprayed at night would be just fine to really deter these guys.  How about a picture of your entire plot or at least the plant and soil?

Comment: Not long.  I only managed to get one fruit and It'll be ready to harvest in another month or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:

This will likely be closed as duplicate.*

Those are aphids - while a few won't hurt a healthy plant, they tend to multiply and then drink so much of the plant sap that they can cause damage.

For small colonies and few plants, you can simply wipe them off. On a larger scale, you might have to resort to spraying an insecticide. (There are "non chemical" options as well.) In enclosed spaces like greenhouses, beneficial insects are a "green" way to go. In your garden, making sure that your plants are in good shape and that there is room for a balanced ecosystem is the key to avoid excessive infestations.

Comment: And white fly...this is the time of year for sure.